# Postgresql equivalent of --i-am-a-dummy

Tags: postgresql, psql

MySQL's command line tool has a flag [--i-am-a-dummy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) that sets execution limits:

> With --safe-updates, you can modify rows only by specifying the key values that identify them, or a LIMIT clause, or both. This helps prevent accidents. Safe-updates mode also restricts SELECT statements that produce (or are estimated to produce) very large result sets.

Is there a way to turn on similar features in psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [proposal for an extension](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/810667ca-fd0d-009c-3cb5-a4a83d8a8ca6%40dalibo.com#c0aa2174a6e31ef3b68029723acdf026) that would do part of this, but it never got finalized.  Perhaps another push could get it done.